# How to use old character sets

Tags: character-set

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS.

I wonder if there is a way to use, with some today app like LibreOffice, old codepage characters set, like the old Atari ST character set:

[image]

And the old 437 character set.

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is interesting is that cp437 does not have wide support on Ubuntu. Checked this on https://packages.ubuntu.com .

There is at least one interesting application named Konwert. It has filters for conversion between various codepages, [including cp437](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/konwert-filters/filelist).

To convert existing file between CP437 and UTF8 use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install konwert

konwert cp437-UTF8 doc437.txt -o docutf8.txt
konwert UTF8-cp437 docutf8.txt -o doc437.txt
```

Comment: WOH! It really works! Thank you so much @N0rbert! BTW, Is there some GUI to this converter app?